# Print all elements of a list preceded by a given one

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to print all the elements of this list who are directly following "apple".

With

```
my_list = ["apple","train","apple","bus"]
```

I would expect the output:

```
(train,bus)
```

But my current code

```
print (my_list[my_list.index("apple") + 1])
```

only outputs the first one, "train".

How can I get all of them?

Comment: There is no problem with the code, I have tested it and i get `train` as an output.

Comment: after which element? Please be more clear!

Comment: It sounds like you want to find *all* instances of a given string in a list, and print all of the elements that immediately follow each of those instances.

Comment: >>> l1 = ["apple", "train","apple", "bus","stone", 'apple', 'stone']                                                    >>> [ l1[enu + 1] for enu, val in enumerate(l1) if val == 'apple' and not enu == len(l1) -1 ]                           ['train', 'bus', 'stone']                                                                                               >>>

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all items directly following an "apple" in your list, your could use a list comprehension, like:

```
my_list = ["apple","train","apple","bus", "apple"]

[my_list[i+1] for i, item in enumerate(my_list) 
              if item == "apple" and i+1 < len(my_list)]
# ['train', 'bus']
```

We keep the next element whenever the current one is "apple" - and we're not at the end of the list.

Comment: @AntonvBR I usually like `itertools`, but I don't see how you would make use of `dropwhile` in this case. Would you write an answer to demonstrate it?

Comment: I wondered about it for a second... If you prefer that version,that's a decisive vote, I edit it! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = ["apple","train","apple","bus"]
index = my_list.index("apple")
print(my_list[index:index+2])
```

Have a look at Python's slice syntax. This will print the sublist from index to index + 2 (**exclusive**).
If you want it as a tuple as you indicated in your question, just wrap it in `tuple()`

Edit: Of course given that you already have `apple` you could also just do

```
print(("apple", my_list[my_list.index("apple") + 1)
```